# Difference between @Max and @DecimalMax (and @Min and @DecimalMin)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

What's the difference between `@Max` and `@DecimalMax`, and `@Min` and `@DecimalMin` in Hibernate Validator?

Looking at the Javadocs, they seem to be enforcing the same constraint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you take a look at the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_validator_reference.pdf), you'll see that the @Min & @Max annotations both have an impact on the Hibernate metadata while @DecimalMin & @DecimalMax don't. Namely, they add check constraints (which effectively improves your relational mapping).

Also @Max & @Min accept a long value, while @DecimalMax & @DecimalMin accept the String representation of a BigDecimal (which makes these the only possible choice if you're dealing with big numbers that exceed Long.MAX_VALUE or are under Long.MIN_VALUE.