# Bean Validation range constraint

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I need to implement range constraints on Entity data fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PAYMENT")
public class Payment extends AbstractEntity {

    //....

    //Something like that
    @Range(minValue = 80, maxValue = 85)
    private Long paymentType;

}
```

I already created validating service, but have to implement many of these cases.

I need the app to throw exception if the inserted number is out of range.

Comment: You can define range using following annotation.
`@Max(85)  
@Min(5)`  and if you want define custom messages for this validation then you need to create custom constraints. Refer this [link](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/24/jpa-constraints/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129825/difference-between-max-and-decimalmax-and-min-and-decimalmin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need Hibernate Validator ([see documentation](http://hibernate.org/validator/))

> ### Hibernate Validator
>
> *The Bean Validation reference implementation.*
>
> Application layer agnostic validation Hibernate Validator **allows to
>   express and validate application constraints.** The default metadata
>   source are annotations, with the ability to override and extend
>   through the use of XML. It is not tied to a specific application tier
>   or programming model and is available for both server and client
>   application programming. But a simple example says more than 1000
>   words:
>
> ```
> public class Car {
>
>    @NotNull
>    private String manufacturer;
>
>    @NotNull
>    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
>    private String licensePlate;
>
>    @Min(2)
>    private int seatCount;
>
>    // ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

With `hibernate-validator` dependency you can define range check

```
@Min(value = 80)
@Max(value = 85)
private Long paymentType;
```

In `pom.xml` add below dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>{hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the specific annotation you are looking for:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Range.html

Example:

```
@Range(min = 1, max =12)
private String expiryMonth;
```

This is also a more beneficial annotation because it will work on Strings or Number variants without using two annotations like is the case with @Max/@Min. @Size is not compatible with Integers.

Answer (score 1):

For integer and long you can use `@Min(value = 80)
@Max(value = 85)`

For BigDecimal `@DecimalMin(value = "80.99999")
@DecimalMax(value = "86.9999")`

Comment: I needed it for BigDecimal. This was it :)